# How to remove eslint single quote rule in React Native default eslint config?

Tags: react-native, eslint

I have set a react-native project with the cli. It works, but I have a very anoying eslint error:

> Strings must use singlequote.eslint(quotes)

I have tried to write this:

```js
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  extends: "@react-native-community",
  rules: {
    avoidEscape: true,
    allowTemplateLiterals: true,
  },
};
```

I also tried to create my own config:

```js
module.exports = {
  globals: {
    Atomics: "readonly",
    SharedArrayBuffer: "readonly",
  },
  parser: "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  extends: ["@react-native-community"],
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: 2018,
    sourceType: "module",
    ecmaFeatures: {
      jsx: true,
    },
  },
  plugins: ["react", "react-hooks"],
  rules: {
    avoidEscape: true,
    allowTemplateLiterals: true,
  },
  settings: {
    react: {
      version: "detect",
    },
  },
  "sort-imports": [
    "error",
    {
      ignoreCase: false,
      ignoreDeclarationSort: false,
      ignoreMemberSort: false,
      memberSyntaxSortOrder: ["none", "all", "multiple", "single"],
    },
  ],
};
```

Nothing works. How to remove this rule?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can turn off any specific rule like so:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "quotes": "off"
  }
}
```